# Changing simulated metrics is messing up my xib

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, autolayout, xcode6

I have a view that I've designed using auto layout constraints. When I use simulated metrics to view the layout for different iPhone sizes things look okay but I've noticed that every time I change to a different iPhone size my xib is also getting modified to display properly for that device.

The problem comes when I install on the device. The last selected "simulated metrics" iPhone size layout is getting installed on the device regardless of the size of the target device (e.g., iPhone 6, 5, ...).

This totally defeats the purpose of using auto layout.

Comment: Some screenshots / images would be helpful here.

Comment: Yeah, I can't see anywhere where I can upload them...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured out my problem.
I was loading the xib using

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

and then adding it to my controller's view as a subview.

But before doing that, I needed to call:

```
view.frame=self.view.frame;
```

There still seem to be some Xcode bugs around this, but this seems to solve my problem for now.